# Store object's state in various stage in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am writing a program to read a file from a directory and store in database the

> various state during this process ie. once read from directory
>   state=read,  then i take backup the file, state = backup, then do some
>   processsing , state = processed and finally delete the file,
>   state=deleted.
>
> at every state change i need to update the database row columns named
>   read,backup,processed, deleted.

Can anyone help me how to implement this in a proper way?

Thanks

Comment: What did you try until now? Have you encountered some problem?

Comment: i implemented state design pattern. i changed the object state, saved to database and moved forward. didnt encountered any problem but not sure what i am doing is the right way.

Comment: Than you should be ok. As long as the code you've wrote is maintainable (without copy-pasted code segments) you're good